# Set 'Start Date' on Datepicker for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

This is my datepicker field:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputBday">Birthday</label>
              <input type="text" name="bday" class="datepicker" required>
            </div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            startDate: '-3y',
            'format' : 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true
            })
        })
 })
```

When I open the datepicker, the start date is the current date!
How to solve?

Comment: what do you mean by startDate? jQuery's datepicker widget doesn't such an option. do you mean [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/#option-minDate)?

Comment: The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled. Is 'datepicker for boostrap' -> http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: did you try `startDate: '-1095',`

Comment: Thanks, but not worked...

Comment: Not sure I get it, `startDate` sets the earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled. Is this not what you're trying to do? If not, you should read the documentation, all you have to do is set the value of the element to whatever date you choose ?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="bday" class="datepicker" value="09/17/2011" required>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. When you are defining the date picker, you can use setDate option:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "10/12/2013");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but I adapted it to my project and still not working = /
The code is identical to yours!

Comment: @JuninhoChr send me your code, may be I can see what is the problem.

Comment: Ths issue of course is that the two of you are working with different datepickers, the OP is using the bootstrap datepicker while this answer uses the jQuery UI datepicker ?

Comment: Started using the jQueryUI datepicker and it worked! Thank you!